# How to archive ivar/property of object in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know how to use NSCoding in some object.

What I do not like is that:
`[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self toFile:path]`

will save also other data (some stuff regarding the object) except from which is defined in
    `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder`

Is there some way to same just one ivar/property of the object, and then restoring it, without saving all other stuff ?

I hope that you can understand my question.

Also, is there some way to make file encrypted ?
I am planing to keep score of game in this way (if there is some other better way please say so).
But I would not like that somebody can change file and in that way fake his score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, write it explicitly to a file on its own, as data, text, JSON formatted text, ...

`NSKeyedArchiver` needs the additional information so that it knows what type of class to create. If you don't want that information to be saved then you can't use `NSKeyedArchiver`.

A simple option is to save as a `plist`. `NSDictionary` makes this easy:

```
NSDictionary *saveDict = @{ @"MyInt" : @( self.intValue ), @"MyBool" : @( self.boolValue ) };
[saveDict writeToFile:... atomically:YES];
```

but, this has limitations on the data types you want to store. So does JSON.

Comment: Can you please provide some code example ? I am new to iOS, so it shard for me to understand it from explanation only :-)

Comment: You need to be specific about what the data to be saved is and what format you're looking for...

Comment: just give example how to save one bool value and one int value. I think that I can follow from there. :-)